# Angular 2 after logout cookie not cleared

Tags: angular, cookies, asp.net-core

In server side I have cleared the cookie for current request but the cookie is not cleared in the browser.

```
public async void LogOut()
    {
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("_FO");
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing from local storage:

```
localStorage.removeItem('_FiFo');
localStorage.removeItem('uniq_expire');
```

Maybe is not the best way.

Comment: It works, but I have already delete the cookie in serverside!